# AngularJS Service breaking Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I'm trying to implement some services on my Angular v1.6.4 app. However I get this error [image: my error] when I import the service in my index.html

This is the content of my service

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.service('SessionService', function() {
    $this.get = function () {
         return true;
    }
 });
```

I didn't even used it in my app. Simply importing it like

```
<script src="path/to/SessionService.js"></script>
```

already brings the error up

As of the home controller, I implemented it like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('home', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

And I called it like

```
<header class="navbar" ng-controller="home"></header>
```

I also made sure I was importing the home controller in my index.html.

I just can't get what I'm missing out. Could you help me, please ?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the first line inside your service file

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.service('SessionService', function() {
    $this.get = function () {
         return true;
    }
 });
```

should be

```
angular.module('myApp')
.service('SessionService', function() {
    $this.get = function () {
         return true;
    }
 });
```

without the `[]`

When you use the square bracket inside angular.module, you redefine a new module. Without you access an existing module

Answer (score 0):

`angular.module('myApp', [])` means you are creating the module `myApp`, and you are doing it twice.

create once the module using `angular.module('myApp', [])` by passing a second argument (`[]`: array of dependent modules) and for referring the module next time onward, use

`angular.module('myApp')` //this will return an reference to the existing module `myApp`

and btw, it will be `this` inside service and not `$this`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I marked @sheplu 's answer as the best answer because he explained what I was doing wrong by showing it on my own code. Your answer is also correct, but other people coming to this question might find his answer more easily understandable :)

Comment: that's ok, whatever is good for the community and other people needs help, is better to do :)